# How to create a multi root flatbuffer json file？

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

How to create a multi root flatbuffer json file？

```
table Login {
    name:string;
    password:string;
}

table Attack {
    damage:short;
}
```

I created the following json file

```json
{
    "Login": {
        "name": "a",
        "password": "a",
    }
}
```

but get error: `no root type set to parse json with`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `root_type Login` to the bottom of your schema file. If you also want to parse JSON from the command-line with `Attack` then stick that into its own schema, or use `--root-type` manually.

Also see the documentation, e.g. https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_using_schema_compiler.html